# Configure iproute2 for multiple NICs and validating

Tags: linux, centos, routing, iproute2

In attempt to avoid split routing for a CentOS 6 server with multiple NICs, I am working on configuring iproute2 to direct traffic that originated from a particular NIC (VLAN) to return only via that NIC instead of the default route set on the server's eth0. This is what it looks like right now.

ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:9b:1c:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.2.130.206/24 brd 10.2.130.255 scope global eth3
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe9b:1c1d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:9b:6c:b3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.2.220.206/24 brd 10.2.220.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe9b:6cb3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:9b:4b:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.2.120.206/24 brd 10.2.120.255 scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe9b:4bb1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:9b:4b:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.2.100.206/24 brd 10.2.100.255 scope global eth2
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe9b:4b14/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route

```
10.2.130.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.2.130.206
10.2.100.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.2.100.206
10.2.220.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.2.220.206
10.2.120.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.2.120.206
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth3  scope link  metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1003
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1004
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth2  scope link  metric 1005
default via 10.2.220.1 dev eth0
```

ip rule

```
0:      from all lookup local
32762:  from 10.2.130.0/24 lookup development
32763:  from 10.2.100.0/24 lookup protected
32764:  from 10.2.120.0/24 lookup external
32765:  from 10.2.220.0/24 lookup management
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Now everything "seems" to be working as intended, but how do I actually validate this?

Comment: Your `ip route` output isn't as useful as it could be since you are only showing the main table.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I actually validate this

Run tcpdump/wireshark, target a specific interface with `-i interface` and generate some traffic that should go through a specific interface using whatever your favorite tools are.  Netcat to a tcp service might be a good option.  Make sure you see everything for the connection, with tcp, make sure you see both directions of the 3 way handshake, and the all the packets for the connection close.